# How to bind the system short cut in a web application?

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I see that the google doc can use many desktop short key, it seems that it listen to the keyboard you type. How can I implement it using javascript? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keydown event:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 102) { // ctrl+f pressed
        e.preventDefault();
        // do something
    }
});
```

Note that this example uses jQuery. It can also be done without jQuery but event handling is not exactly the same in all browsers so I'd highly suggest you to use jQuery or another Javascript framework.